External spread spectrum phase-shifted clocks versus unsynchronised spread spectrum in multiple buck converters
I'm working on a design where I have a need to generate about 10A at 5V across a long bar-shaped board. This is generated from an incoming 12V DC rail. For a number of reasons (physical constraints, thermals, EMI) it makes more sense in my application to use multiple smaller buck converters rather than one large one, producing separate 5V rails for different physical regions of the board. For the purposes of this question, let's assume four buck converters.
I'm looking at buck converters in the 1.5-10MHz switching frequency range. These almost invariably come with a SYNC pin which allows their switching frequencies to be synchronised by an external clock driver. Some of these converters also support spread-spectrum clocking when they are not being synchronised. These features are helpful for mitigating EMI issues and improving PDN integrity.
It appears to me that there are two potential options here.
Option A is to use an external clock generator IC with spread-spectrum support, and generate four clock outputs from that. Ideally these clocks would be shifted 90 degrees in phase to minimise dI/dt on the upstream 12V rail, but the cheaper clockgen options (e.g. Si5351) often don't support that much timing skew control at lower frequencies; as a result the clock phases might be at something like 0°, 45°, 180°, 225°, but this seems generally fine. The clockgen can then be configured for spread-spectrum, e.g. ±1% center spread at ~30kHz rate. All converters operate at the same frequency at any point in time, since the spread-spectrum is global.
Option B is to not synchronise the converters, and use converters with their own spread-spectrum feature. Since nothing is synchronised and all the converters are shifting their switching frequency over time, there will be constant drift. Any overlap between switching edges will be minimised by the pseudorandom behaviour of the system. The converters can also independently adjust their own switching frequency as needed.
Assuming that the cost is roughly equal, what are the pros and cons here?

Do you know that an EMI issue exists in the first place? Is this a particularly demanding application (say, 20dB+ below commercial levels?), or is layout expected to be too challenging (congested design, narrow board, etc.)?

@TimWilliams It's a long narrow board with a fairly dense layout, and there will be a dozen of these boards operating in the same environment. I also take pride in the robustness of my designs and would prefer to over-engineer EMI reduction than save a few hours and cents. That said, even if I didn't strictly need synchronised clocks here, the question stands by itself as a matter of good practice.

I would prefer a fixed phase relationship between the converters. In this case the bulk capacitors on the 12 V input side never must provide the higher current of multiple converters switching randomly at the same time.
EMI filtering is simpler, because the noise bandwidth is much smaller.
It may be an issue to route all these clock lines along the bar. You could place a chain of inverters, say 6 gates from a 74HC14 or a single 74AHC1G17 with R/C delay at the input, between the converter sync inputs. This will also produce a fixed phase shift using only one clock signal.

I ended up talking this through with some folks who do a lot more power electronics than I do, and they pointed me in the right direction: option A.
There are two key problems with option B: beat frequencies and unintentional synchronisation.
If you run multiple buck converters with independent spread-spectrum clocks, there will be intermodulation between the nearby frequencies. This will create a beat frequency at the delta between the frequencies - in this case, in the range of 0-250kHz. These frequencies are far harder to filter out than the MHz range.
In addition, it is possible for the buck converters to unintentionally track each other rather than operate psuedorandomly due to mutual crosstalk overriding the normal variations in component values and parasitics. They may settle in-phase with each other under relatively constant current load, then slip back out of phase after a perturbation. This leads to more complex EMI behaviours and increased ripple current on high-side rail capacitors.

Well, "will" is a strong word. Could be. Depends how the regulators respond to their environment. I would just as well guess they'll ignore external sync and go on their merry way, most likely being completely incoherent -- that leaves the catch, maybe they randomly sync, because the control does actually depend on environment (e.g. VCC noise), or they just start up in sync and happen to have perfectly matched clocks. But we can't know for certain whether either outcome is true. The advantage of A is not so much electrical, but the design assurance of avoiding the above uncertainty.

@TimWilliams I'm not sure where you got "will" from regarding them syncing. I said "it is possible". And yes, the issue on that front is a lack of confidence on the behaviour.

"They" did -- "there will be intermodulation"

@TimWilliams Yes, there will be intermodulation of the upstream currents, leading to beat frequencies. That's unrelated to the paragraph about tracking each other, which may occur.

No, in general there will not -- the upstream path will most likely be linear and currents superimpose without mixing!  (But you see a certain tension here: there's only so much critique that is worth bringing upon an unsourced, unattributed quote; but yet it stands prominently in plain view. The source will never see this feedback, and you don't deserve that criticism since it's not your words.) (Put another way: I don't know whose misunderstanding it is; though since this point apparently wasn't obvious, it turns out to be useful to point out.)

@TimWilliams Your comment talked about the synchronisation, not the intermodulation, so you can see the source of my confusion. The tension you describe is self-created; perhaps don't seek to dismiss people's questions by supposing that they didn't bother to evaluate their requirements, especially when the question would stand for good practice reasons regardless. I appreciate the technical feedback but not the manner in which you provided it. But we're both adults and I'm willing to move past that to resolve this question. Could you clarify whether upstream ferrites, CMCs, etc. affect this?

No, not dismissing -- more in the sense of -- and yes, I'm terrible at explaining these sorts of (meta) things, my apologies -- if the source had come here and provided the answer themselves, it would stand by itself, not reflecting upon anyone else, and can be criticized alone; whereas containing it in another (your) answer, makes it more complicated. Or, put another way: it might be worth asking the validity of the point first, in which case it would be a question not an answer -- the confusion in that sense is an inversion of hierarchy. It's an unfamiliar situation to me, anyways.

For my part, I only wanted to bring attention to the incongruity: a linear system does not exhibit intermodulation; there are cases where people bring up that word (like that a two-tone signal on the oscilloscope has a slow envelope), inappropriately (the oscilloscope isn't nonlinear, your eyes / thought process are!), and I wonder if your source is exhibiting such a confusion. I don't aim to comment on the other aspects, just a pointed comment at this. (Which might well be a "throw away" part of the answer overall, and so too these comments.)

Well okay that and the randomness aspect; which supports your conclusion, but via different reasoning.
